# Is there a way to display the answers to randomly generated addition questions?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to show the answers to some randomly generated questions but the only way I can think of doing it gives an answer to a question that is not seen.  The code below produces 10 questions correctly but I need to find a way of displaying the answers. Any help would be appreicated.

Thanks

```
function createWorksheet1() {
        
        var totalQuestions = 10;
        var difficulty = 1000;
        var ans;
        
        //column1 easy
        for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
            var firstNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
            var secondNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
            // var ans = firstNumber + secondNumber gives answer to unseen question
            document.getElementById('column1').innerHTML += firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + "<br>"+"<br>"+"<br>" 
            // document.getElementById('column1').innerHTML += ans  seems to give an answer to a unseen problem
        }
}
```

Comment: *"Answers"* not sure to understand... what answers you're talking about.

Comment: The code above produces 10 questiosn of randomly generated numbers such as 1025 + 1012. I want to be able to show the answer to this question but can not seem to find a way to get that answer to show on screen.

Comment: What means in your own words *"gives an answer to a question that is not seen"*? What means *"seems to give an answer to a unseen problem"*? What the actual problem here?

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]? With some HTML, CSS if needed etc?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3ohpmys2/   When you clcik on the word addition 10 questions are generated. I would like a way to show the answers to these questions.

Comment: First of: don't use inline `onclick` attribute handlers. Use addEventListtener() instead. Also, seems like you're code is just ready to have way too many such functions. That's not the way we should do programming. Instead pass arguments to your function. And all you'll need is a single function, not several like `createWorksheet1`, `createWorksheet2`, `createWorksheet3` and who knows how many...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- simply insert the result into the HTML alike string
- use a single function not many (like you're planning to use) - JS is not about repeating code. Keep DRY. Pass arguments to your function instead
- don't use `<br><br><br>` use CSS instead.

```js
const createWorksheet = (selector, totalQuestions = 10, difficulty = 100) => {

  const elCol = document.querySelector(selector);
  let html = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
    const firstNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
    const secondNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
    const ans = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    
    // Concatenate HTML-alike string
    html += `<div class="calc">${firstNumber} + ${secondNumber} = ${ans}</div>`;
  }
  
  elCol.innerHTML = html;   // insert only once:
};

createWorksheet("#column-easy", 10, 100);
createWorksheet("#column-difficult", 10, 1000);
```

```css
.calc {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<h3>Easy</h3>
<div id="column-easy"></div>
<h3>Difficult</h3>
<div id="column-difficult"></div>
```

Your task now is to create also an additional argument that accepts multiplication, division etc, pass it as argument and handle that logic within that single function to be later used i.e: like:

```js
createWorksheet("#column-easy", 10, 10, "+");
createWorksheet("#column-medium", 10, 100, "*");
createWorksheet("#column-difficult", 10, 1000, "/");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will take a look at this and try to work through it. I am doing this as a "fun" activity in holiday downtime from teaching so am a complete novice. Your help is very much apprieciated.